# Java Swing: JTable with subitems

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my Project i want to have a Table with items that may have subitems, like in the Eclipse 'Problems' View. (Indexes 2-17 should be Subitems of 1)

My Project so far:
[Overview of my Project](http://b04.img-up.net/tesseract_306e.png)

What i want to have:

[image]

*Content of Main.java:*

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        table = new JTable(new CostumTableModel());
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        contentPane.add(table);
    }

}
```

*Content of CostumTableModel.java:*

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class CostumTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    public CostumTableModel() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        if (col == 0) {
            return row + 1;
        }
        return row * col;
    }

}
```

Full Version of my Code, except this feature can be found at my Github.
Does anybody of you know how to do this? I'm searching the whole day for a solution, but didn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/)

See printscreen:

[image]